# C#: Replacing loops with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, loops

What would be the equivalent for these code samples in LINQ (C#):

```
    int[] items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int number = -1;
foreach (int i in items) 
{
    if (i == 5) 
    {
        number = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

And how would you replace a for loop with two (or more) conditions in LINQ?
*(it is similar to the code above, couldn't come up with a better example. Imagine that other conditions or checks happen there in the for loop)*

```
    int[] items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int number = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length && number == -1; i++) 
{
    if (items[i] == 5)
        number = items[i];
}
```

And the third piece of code, how would this be translated in LINQ:

```
    List<int> items2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int i = items2.Count - 1;

for (; i > 0; i--)
    items2.RemoveAt(i);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last one looks like `items2.Clear();` to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first two are pretty odd, but basically they're effectively:

```
int number = items.Contains(5) ? 5 : -1;
```

or

```
int number = items.Any(x => x == 5) ? 5 : -1;
```

An alternative way of doing this:

```
int number = items.Where(x => x == 5).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
```

If you can come up with more realistic operations, we can come up with more sensible LINQ queries :)

The third snippet can't really be translated into LINQ as it's not a *query* - it's *mutating* the list.

Comment: How about this:

    private T FindLargestKey()
    {
      if (this.Count == 0) return default(T);

      T largestKey = this[0];
      foreach (T key in this.List)
      {
        if (KeyLarger(key)) largestKey = key;
      }

      return largestKey;
    }

Comment: @juFo: You typically don't make modifications with LINQ - you create a new list (or whatever) with the newly-required sequence. As for your FindLargestKey, that sounds like `sequence.DefaultIfEmpty().Max()`.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon points out, the last one can't be translated to LINQ. However, it can be simplified as:

```
var survivers = 1;
items2.RemoveRange(survivers , items2.Count - survivers);
```

Comment: well the last item survives (or if you change it, the last 2 or 3 items survive). (see i > 0 or change 0 to 4) So Clear is not right here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out with RemoveRange, forgot about it.